# Не могу запустить eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Поставил win7x64, теперь не могу запустить eclipse. Выдает такую ошибку:

[image]

В системе установлены след. компоненты:

[image]

В winXP все запускается. Что нужно сделать, чтобы в семерке заработало?

Comment: может эклипс 32битный?

Comment: а че еклипс для пхп?

Comment: проверьте path, мне кажется там не прописан путь к java

Comment: проверьте eclipse.ini, там должно быть что-то вроде

    -vm
    c:/где_у_вас_там_установлена_java/jre/bin/javaw.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доустановил java до следующего состояния, все заработало:

[image]

Comment: Видимо eclipse 32-битный, скачивал отсюда http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt/downloads

Где скачать 64-битный? Какие отличия в работе? Тот что я скачал вообще актуальный? Для PHP

Answer (score 2):

Скачивать надо с eclipse.org! Но я не видел там PHP Developers. Поэтому используйте например phpDesigner. (Я так понял для php)

Comment: Там есть PHP Developers, но 32 битный.